# List.setAdapter(thadapter); not work always + screen errors

Tags: java, android, listview

Hello I have a problwm witch Listview.

I use listview for show items in list.

I have activity where is Listview. And If I longpress on row in listview open popup (dialog) where I can edit word in row.

If edit finish I Call this

```
    AddItemInPacage.obnovitem=true;
    AddItemInPacage.indexitem=poz;
    AddItemInPacage.novyitem=novypacage;
```

Boolean is for Timer if is true Start This method

```
public void ZmenItem(int indexzmeny,String nove) {

    ListAdapter.clear();

    for (int i=1;i<prvy.getPacageItem2(indexpacage)+1;i++) {

        ListAdapter.add(String.valueOf(prvy.citajItem(indexpacage,i)));
    }

    ListAdapter.set(indexzmeny,nove);


    Toast.makeText(this, "citam "+ ListAdapter.get(indexzmeny), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    thadapter = new MyThumbnailAdapter(getApplication(), R.layout.list_row, ListAdapter);

    List.setAdapter(thadapter);
    thadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Everything is OK when I while I not open the same row. If edited  row for some times in row Program not work good.

Everything is good while this line  List.setAdapter(thadapter); after thise line is Variables good too, but listview in display not rewrite. 
Why?

I have three  times this  List.setAdapter(thadapter); on program but on OnCreate method and when Put new row in listview... So when Edited row I call only thise method ↑↑ which sometimes rewrite good and sometimes not.

Because Thise program isn't it 100% good :(

```
ListView List;
    MyThumbnailAdapter thadapter = null;
    ArrayList<String> ListAdapter = new ArrayList<String>();
```

---

This is my Adapter

```
public class MyThumbnailAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    ArrayList<String> arr;
    private TextView text;

    public MyThumbnailAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<String> objects) {

        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        this.arr = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = null;
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);
        TextView textnumber = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);
        ImageView delButton = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_del);

      Typeface  robtoLight = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf");
        textnumber.setTypeface(robtoLight);

        delButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                arr.remove(position);
                thadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Item deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        textnumber.setText(arr.get(position));


        textnumber.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

                for (int i=ListAdapter.size()-1;i>=0;i--) {
                    //      for (int i = 0; i < ListAdapter.size() ; i++) {
                    try {
                        prvy.pridajItemRemove(ListAdapter.get(i), indexpacage, i+1);
                    } catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                        prvy.Nulak(indexpacage,i);
                    }
                }

                prvy.setPacageItem2(ListAdapter.size(),indexpacage);
                prvy.setPocItem(ListAdapter.size());

                for (int i=ListAdapter.size();i<99;i++) {
                    prvy.Nulak(indexpacage,i+1);
                }

                Serializuj(prvy,nazovtripu);


                EditItemDialog cdd=new EditItemDialog(AddItemInPacage.this,nazovtripu,position,indexpacage);
                cdd.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
                cdd.show();


                return true;
            }

        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

I put picture

[image: Wrong Image]

Sometimes if I edit row Toas read good string, but Listview no rewrite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need synchronized confirm edit in Dialog with medhod which rewrite Listview.

Or switch sequence  from

```
AddItemInPacage.obnovitem=true;
    AddItemInPacage.indexitem=poz;
    AddItemInPacage.novyitem=novypacage;
```

to

```
    AddItemInPacage.indexitem=poz;
    AddItemInPacage.novyitem=novypacage;

    AddItemInPacage.obnovitem=true;
```

Because If AddItemInPacage.obnovitem=true; first Activity work with old information in variable novypacage. And when variable novypacage is full from dialog. Listview finish work with old information in this variable.

Comment: This doesn't appear to answer your question

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

> ListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Hoping ListAdapter is name of your adapter

Comment: Sorry I edited up.. ListAdapter is ArrayList Here haven't notifyDataSetChanged(). 

This method have in  MyThumbnailAdapter thadapter.
And It's be in code. :(

Comment: I put picture on better explain